# Updating Oracle Table from Excel VBA Macro using ODBC connection

Tags: oracle, excel, vba, odbc, ado

I have a sheet in Excel 2010 which pulls data in QueryTables from an Oracle database, connected via an ODBC DSN.

I need to take data from the spreadsheet and use it to update a table in the same Oracle database.  I cannot do an update from a QueryTable, but that is the only connection method I have been able to get to work with the ODBC.

I have tried setting up a ADODB connection, but I am getting a

```
'Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005'):

Automation error
Unspecified error
```

Here is the code I used:

```
Sub Upload_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    With cn
        .Provider = "MSDASQL"
        .ConnectionString = "DSN=xcognosD;"
        .Open
    End With

    cn.Close
End Sub
```

Added note, I am on Windows 7 using a 64 bit odbc driver, connecting to Oracle 11 database.

Comment: You might find insight using the macro recorder and copying how it does the connection

Comment: What action should I perform to record a macro that connects without a QueryTable?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

Comment: My Connection string follows the convention of DSN;UID;PWD;. This is a system ODBC, which has the user id and password stored in the ODBC, so all I should have to specify is the DSN.  I have tried putting the UID and PWD in the Connection String, but it generated the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provider "MSDASQL" is [Microsoft's OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2007/11/10/msdasql-oledb-provider-for-odbc-drivers.aspx).  It is quite old, and is now deprecated.  It is really only for use with older databases for which there are no OLE DB providers.  It is also 32-bit-Only, so it won't work with 64 bit providers (such as the one you are trying to use).  You would be better off trying an OLE DB driver.

The [MS OLEDB provider for Oracle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is "MSDAORA" (which should be pre-installed on your machine) and [Oracle's own OLEDB provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-089115.html) is "OraOLEDB.Oracle".  You would be best advised to download the latest Oracle-provided provider, as MSDAORA is also deprecated.

You would need to download and install the Oracle provider (if you haven't already)

```
.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
```

You would also need to set the `.ConnectionString`.  Have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/ for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the 'Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' is excel's default 'There was a problem with Oracle and I dont know what it is.

First I found out that my odbc was pointing to an old DB that no longer existed.  After updating the odbc, I still got the same error.

However the error no longer happened on the '.Open' portion, but on the .Execute where I was attempting to do an update.  Eventually I figured out that the user did not have access to do an update to the table I was targeting.

So when you get an 'Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' error, check your connections and permissions, they are likely wrong.

Here is the final code I used that worked after fixing permissions:

```
Sub Upload_Click1()
    Dim Oracon
    Dim recset
    Dim cmd

    Set Oracon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Oracon.Open "Data Source=xcognosD;"

    Oracon.Execute "update xstore set last_update_date = sysdate where store_cd = '0000'"

    Oracon.Close

End Sub
```