# make Sql Server database public (allow read and write within network)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vba

**How can I modify an Sql Server database properties to make it public so that all users within the network can read and write to it?** (they will do so through VBA code)
The method I used until now was granting access from DB Security to the network logins/users.

Desired method: I would like to have the database as public and alter the VBA code so that some actions are allowed/restricted based on network username.

Comment: Does your company use Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is retrieve the user_id of the user in VBA with

```
environ('username')
```

and access the database via a server script.

- Create table where you store the users of your internal network (via Active Directory you could use LDAP, otherwise you store the id's yourself);
- Create an Ajax call from VBA to the server script and check if the user exists;

I refer to this answer I formulated before on how to create the Ajax call:
[Updating Oracle Table from Excel VBA Macro using ODBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835640/updating-oracle-table-from-excel-vba-macro-using-odbc-connection/18892448#18892448)

- Perform all database transactions from the server script (not from VBA directly to the db). You can send the necessary sql criteria with as GET parameters with the url string (check the link on how to do this via Ajax);

Additionally you can embed an extra security by sending a self created key from the vba tool to the server script (this can be hard coded in the VBA code) and verify this before performing any supplementary actions.
This in order to verify if the VBA tool at the client side should have access to the script.

Comment: Thank you very much Kim! Can you also tell me how to make the database public? At the moment I DON'T condition the reading/writing to and from the database by the network login or anything else. If the database was public, these actions would function but now they don't (so I have to grant to privileges in Sql Server for each user, precisely because the db is private, probably by default).

Comment: The database should not be public. With the server script, you manage the connection to your database; this is where you enter the credentials for db login before you execute the sql transactions.

Comment: For what concerns the assignment of specific user roles and permissions, you better write a class in PHP/ASP to manage these roles / permissions. As the root user, it means that you have all permissions; you can assign permissions to the other users in the form of roles (eg. manager, regular user, ...). Then you say if the user has a certain role, (s)he has permission to execute certain queries (in this scope). I suggest to read about RBAC or Role Based Access Control.